# adding values to a dictionary using foreach loop

Tags: c#, dictionary, foreach, console-application

I am trying to generate a graph that adds points one by one using a start point and a `dictionary`, the dictionary is the form of `dictionary<int, int>` before carrying out a path finding algorithm. I would like to populate the dictionary based on two lists of `int` values, `caveConnections` and `connectionWeights` respectively. The point can have  more than one connection hence the need for a loop to add the values.

the first `int` added to the dictionary is being read line by line from a text file. the second `int` value is to be added from a `stack`.

I'm unsure on how to achieve this. The output I am trying to achieve is as follows;

```
Graph g = new Graph();
g.add_vertex(1, new Dictionary<int, int>() {{2, 7}, {3, 8}});
g.add_vertex(2, new Dictionary<int, int>() {{1, 7}, {6, 2}});
g.add_vertex(3, new Dictionary<int, int>() {{1, 8}, {6, 6}, {7, 4}});
g.add_vertex(4, new Dictionary<int, int>() {{6, 8}});
g.add_vertex(5, new Dictionary<int, int>() {{8, 1}});
g.add_vertex(6, new Dictionary<int, int>() {{2, 2}, {3, 6}, {4, 8}, {7, 9}, {8, 3}});
g.add_vertex(7, new Dictionary<int, int>() {{3, 4}, {6, 9}});
g.add_vertex(8, new Dictionary<int, int>() {{5, 1}, {6, 3}});
```

Text file contents;

```
4 
4 5 
5 6 7 
1 5 6 
2 3 4 
3 4 
3
```

Stack built as follows;

```
Stack<String> connectionStack = new Stack<string>();
List<int> connectionData = new List<int>();
foreach (String s in caveConnections)
{
    connectionStack.Push(s);
}
```

Stack Contents;

> 2,8,3,2,14,5,7,6,11,2,11,6,14,1

any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: and how do you know that if an item goes to current dictionary, or should move to next one? could you provide the text file and stack?

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani  It should move to the next dictionary when it reaches the end of the line of text from the file, i have amended the question to include the text file contents

Comment: are these `int`s in the text file, comma separated?, are their count is the same as those in stack?

Comment: they are currently strings separated by a space however can be separated using a comma, as they are read in they are converted to `int` values. The stack has the same number of `int` values as the text file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("ints.txt");
Graph g = new Graph();
for(int i =0; i< lines.Liength; i++)
{
     string[] ints = lines[i].Split(' ');
     Dictionary<int, int> dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
     for(int j = 0; j<ints.Length;j++)
        if(!dict.ContainsKey(int.Parse(ints[i].Trim())))
            dict.Add(int.Parse(ints[i].Trim()), int.Parse(connectionStack.Pop()));
     g.add_vertex(i+1, dict);
}
```

Here of course if the count of stack is less than ints in the text file, you will have an Exception.

Comment: thanks for that, i am however getting an error stating that a key has already been added to the dictionary. is it possible to have it read only one line at  a time? the number of lines is the same as the total number of caves in this case that is 7

Comment: @bdg it creates a new dictionary for each line, if you are getting that error, it means that you have duplicate values in one line

Comment: ah right, its the connection weights that are causeing the error, is there any way to ignore the fact that a duplicate value that is added?

Comment: check my edited answer (`if(!dict.ContainsKey(int.Parse(ints[i].Trim()))`) I don't know about your code, but you may need to pop anyway, if you don't want to mess up the order.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I am now getting an error stating the the stack is empty. just  to clarify it is the values in the stack that are causing the issue, I've amended the question to contain the stack contents if that is of any use?

Comment: That is the Exception I had warned you in the beginning. _Here of course if the count of stack is less than ints in the text file, you will have an Exception_. I know nothing about your code, so I won't be able of much help, however, you may break the loops (or if this code is in a method, then return) when stack gets empty.

Comment: no problem ill see what i can get from here, Thanks for you're help has been very useful to get an understanding on how this worked

Comment: @bdg glad it helped.